# Checar se usuário já existe codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Olá, estou com um dificuldade para verificar se o nome de um dependente já foi cadastrado.
Tenho um formulário onde a pessoa pode adicionar até 5 nomes de dependentes e apos isso é gerado uma guia com os nomes.

Campo do formulário, tem um botão para adicionar mais campos.

```
    <input type="text" name="nome_dep[]" id="nome_dep" placeholder="Nome do Dependente" class="form-control>
```

Pagina do Controller

```
$nome = $this->input->post('nome_dep');
$nbanco = "SELECT `nome_dependente` FROM `beneficios_dependentes` WHERE `nome_dependente` IN ? ";

    $nome_existe = $this->db->query($nbanco,array($nome))->result_array();

    if (empty($nome_existe))
    {
        echo "Não tem nome no banco";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Tem nome no banco";
    }
```

Minha dificuldade está em consultar se o nome do dependente já foi cadastrado, por exemplo: ele cadastrou joão - OK, mas outro dia ele cadastrou João e a Maria está caindo que já tem o nome cadastrado no banco. 
Eu preciso fazer um insert caso ele não foi cadastrado e um update se já estiver cadastrado

Comment: Mas Existem homônimos, o correto não sería adicionar o `nome_dependente` e o `cpf_dependente`, para que você possa comparar os CPF's e não os nomes?
A final existem muitos "Luiz Inácio Lula", mas nem todos roubam países. alguns só querem programar.

Comment: kkkk, vou trocar o nome do perfil kkkk, então os dependentes estão vinculados com um associado, será que consigo algo nesse sentido?

Comment: Acho que ficaria menos "correto", suponha que um associado tenha filhos gêmeos com o mesmo nome... ele não poderia colocar os dois filho porque eles tem os mesmos nomes?
Porque o `SELECT nome_dependente FROM beneficios_dependentes WHERE nome_dependente = $nome AND associado_id = $id_do_associado` não serviria?
Como estão suas tabelas?

Comment: Tabela beneficios_dependentes tem: id_beneficios_dependentes, nome_dependente, associado_dependentes (FK), o problema é que o nome vem num array name="nome_dep[]", eu preciso separar cada um e verificar na tabela. A questão dos gêmeos acredito que não terá problema, mas vc deu uma ideia de adicionar o RG

Comment: Eu nunca usei o codeignite, mas se o problema é como fazer o `select` para todos os nomes de um `array`, você usa algum laço de repetição como o `foreach()`. vou publicar a resposta como acredito que ficaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($nomes as $nome) 
    {
        $this->db->select('nome_dependente');
        $this->db->where('nome_dependente', $nome);
        $query = $this->db->get('beneficios_dependentes');
        $resultado = $query->result();
        if (empty($resultado))
        {
          $insere = $this->beneficios_model->insere($id, $dados, $nome);
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Tem nome no banco";
        }
    }
```

eu fiz assim, estou arrumando, mas deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, seu problema é em executar a pesquisa pela quantidade de beneficiarios que chegarem pelo post

```
$nomes = $this->input->post('nome_dep');
  foreach ($nome as $nome) {

    $nbanco = "SELECT `nome_dependente` FROM `beneficios_dependentes` WHERE `nome_dependente` = $nome";

    $nome_existe = $this->db->query($nbanco,array($nome))->result_array();

    if (empty($nome_existe))
    {
      echo "Não tem nome no banco";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Tem nome no banco";
    }
  }
```

Testa aí e me dá um retorno

Comment: eu arrumei é deu certo, muito obrigado por sua ajuda

Comment: Se puder marca como resposta certa